# Reference request: Conditional posterior for bayesian hierarchical linear regression model

Tags: regression, bayesian, references, hierarchical-bayesian

I am searching for a reference computing the conditional posterior distribution of a bayesian hierarchical linear regression model of the standard form:
$$y\sim N(X\beta,\sigma I)\\
\sigma^2 \sim IG(v_1,v_2) \\
\beta|\mu,\sigma^2 \sim N(\mu,\Lambda_0 ^{-1})\\
\mu \sim N(\mu_0,\Lambda_1 ^{-1})
$$
In my perception this model is a standard example on how to work with hierarchical models, however, I failed in finding one source that gives me the conditional posterior distributions such that I can set up a Gibbs sampler. Each and every snippet summarizing this computation is welcome, I would also be happy to create this computation in this post in order to make it available easier. (Source code of the Gibbs sampler is also appreciated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized, that ** Markov Chain Monte Carlo: Stochastic Simulation for Bayesian Inference (Texts in Statistical Science) ** provides the condtitional posteriors.